# How to perform a task in MySQL after a scheduled time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net

I am new to SQL and I want to update the Amount in the amount field. For example in every month in 3 months I want to add 100 to 500. And when the 3rd month comes It will automatically transfer the data to another table

This is the the code I have done so far, but its not working properly. Its for adding amount in the amount table. I have no idea how to transfer data in scheduled time

```
  DELIMITER $$

  CREATE EVENT myevents
  ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE

  DO BEGIN
  INSERT INTO s (AMOUNT)
  VALUES (100);
  END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this below code to create schedule and interval..

```
CREATE
[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
     EVENT
     [IF NOT EXISTS]
     event_name
ON SCHEDULE schedule
[ON COMPLETION [NOT] PRESERVE]
[ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE]
[COMMENT 'comment']
DO event_body;
```

--schedule:
            AT timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...
  |         EVERY interval
              [STARTS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...]
             [ENDS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...]

interval:
                 quantity {YEAR | QUARTER | MONTH | DAY | HOUR | MINUTE |
                   WEEK | SECOND | YEAR_MONTH | DAY_HOUR | DAY_MINUTE |
                     DAY_SECOND | HOUR_MINUTE | HOUR_SECOND | MINUTE_SECOND}